# Invoking C# delegate from F# - Is there a cleaner syntax?

Tags: f#, delegates, syntactic-sugar

In C#, if a delegate is defined as follow:

```cs
delegate void A();
A a = () => {Console.WriteLine("Test")};
```

It can be invoked with:

```cs
a.Invoke(); // Works
a();        // Also works
```

In F#, the C# delegate can be invoked:

```
a.Invoke() // Works fine.
a()        // Error: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

Why can't I use the 2nd method in F#? In C#, does the () operator simply map to the Invoke method, or is there something else happening underneath. Is there a cleaner syntax in F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do. F# and C# use different types to represent things that can be invoked. In C#, the natural thing to use is a delegate (like `Func<T1, T2>`) and in F#, the natural thing to use is an F# function value (`T1 -> T2`). Invoking delegate from F# is uglier just like invoking an F# function from C# is ugly.

The best thing to do is to use the native representation most of the time and turn delegates into functions (or vice versa) at the boundary.

So, when writing F# code, I would just use functions:

```
let foo f = f(10) + f(32)
```

But when exposing this to C#, I would write an operation that accepts a delegate and converts it to a function before calling `foo`:

```
type CSharpFriendly() =
  static member Foo(f:Func<int, int>) = foo f.Invoke
```

This also uses the fact that writing just `f.Invoke` returns a nice F# function value.